# How to prove subadditivity of joint entropy?

Tags: self-study, entropy

I've been kind of stuck on this exercise for the last hours.

Heres everything I know and everything I'm allowed to use to prove it:

Let $X= \{w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$ and $Y = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ be two discrete random variables with $\text{wlog } |X| \leq |Y|$.

Let the joint entropy be defined as:

$$ H(X,Y) =  - \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m p_{i,j} \log(p_{i,j}) $$

I dont know if $X $ and  $Y$ are dependent or independent. All I know is that $p_{i,j}  = Pr[X=w_i \land Y=v_j]$

Lemma of Gibbs is all I have; I don't know if I'm allowed to use conditional probabilities.

The assignment was to prove the subadditivity of the joint entropy of $X$ and $Y$: $$H(X,Y) \leq H(X) + H(Y) $$

Full solutions discouraged, please post hints, I believe I'd learn more that way.

Comment: can anyone help ? is there anything I can improve about my question ?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the KL divergence
$$D_{KL}(p_{XY} \| p_X \otimes p_Y) \geq 0$$

where $p_{XY}$ is the probability distribution on $X, Y$ defined by $p_{ij}$ in your notation. $p_X$ is $p_{XY}$ marginalized over $Y$. $p_X \otimes p_Y$ is the direct product of $p_X$ and $p_Y$, so
$$(p_X \otimes p_Y)(x, y) = p_X(x) p_Y(y)$$